# How can I get product description with Amazon product API 5?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I use Amazon product API 5 and want to retrieve products with description. In the old version this was possible with itemlookup. In the new version there is only getitem. But this does not provide a product description in the Json. Does anyone have an idea how to get the product description via the API?